# Paypal recurring payment with additional free subscription at end of month

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

i am creating paypal recurring payment i want to give addition one cycle free at the end of the month, like if you subscribe for 6 months you will get 1 month for free.

how to setup this in paypal express checkout recurring payment.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, change your pricing structure. So if 1 month costs 9,99, give 6 months for 49,99. (Effective, 1 month free).

Comment: There are two ways, either you set up 3 different subscribe buttons (For example, 1 for a month, 1 for 6 months and 1 for a year. Or you add a dropdown via paypals standard checkup wizard where they chose the period they want to subscribe for.